# How to escape accolade characters in CMake

Tags: cmake, escaping

I'm manually generating a QtCreator project file (.pro) from CMake.

At some point, I need to write `$${VAR}` to the .pro file. So I need to escape both the `$` character and the `{` `}`.

I found out how to protect the `$` sign, here is how I proceed:

```
macro( QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR var line )
    set( ${var} "${${var}}\n${line}\n" )
endmacro()

set(PRO_CONTENT "#Generated by CMake scripts!")
# Adding many other stuff here....
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(PRO_CONTENT "TARGET = \\$\\$VAR" )
file(WRITE file.pro ${PRO_CONTENT} )
```

This generates file.pro:

```
#Generated by CMake scripts!
...
TARGET = $$VAR
```

But how can I generate? I could not find out how to escape the accolades:

```
#Generated by CMake scripts!
...
TARGET = $${VAR}
```

I tried:

```
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(PRO_CONTENT "TARGET = \\$\\$\\{VAR\\}" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(PRO_CONTENT "TARGET = \\$\\$\{VAR\}" )
```

with no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `macro` call consume one level of escaping. It is known [bug](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=5389), but CMake developers don't want to fix it (for backward compability reason).

Originally, in CMake there is no needs to escape `{` character; only `${` combination has a special meaning. So you only need to escape `$` sign. Because of `macro` call, you need to escape it twice:

```
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(PRO_CONTENT "TARGET = \\\$\\\${VAR}" )
```

You may implement `QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR` as a function:

```
function( QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR var line )
    set( ${var} "${${var}}\n${line}\n" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

In that case, escaping will be simplified:

```
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(PRO_CONTENT "TARGET = \$\${VAR}" )
```

Comment: Have you actually tested that? Because when I do so, generated output file is `TARGET = $` when `TARGET = $${VAR}` is expected. The `\\$` is definitely needed and it works, my problem is escaping the accolades.

Comment: Sorry, checked everything except `macro` usage. I edited answer for that case.

Comment: Great! This fixed it . Thanks