# CMake: Set variable from nested function calls

Tags: cmake

CMake variables management is driving me nuts....

I'd like to call a function, who calls another function in order to modify a variable that will end up to be the content of a file to be written.

It looks like this:

```
function( QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR var line )
  set( ${var} "${${var}}\n${line}\n" PARENT_SCOPE )
endfunction()

function( QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR var relline debugline )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "release:${relline} (two functions call)" )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "debug:${debugline} (two functions call)" )
endfunction()

QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(FILE_CONTENT "#Generated by CMake scripts!")
QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "foo" "bar" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "release:foo (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "debug:bar (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "EOF" )

file(WRITE myFile.txt ${FILE_CONTENT} )
```

This generates myFile.txt:

```
#Generated by CMake scripts!
release:foo (single function call)
debug:bar (single function call)
EOF
```

When I would expect:

```
#Generated by CMake scripts!
release:foo (two functions call)
debug:bar (two functions call)
release:foo (single function call)
debug:bar (single function call)
EOF
```

Most likely, the problem is that `(set ... PARENT_SCOPE)` sets the variable in `QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR` but not in its parent scope...

I tried to replace `functions` by `macros`, then I get the right output, but introduces a bug ([How to escape accolade characters in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583580/how-to-escape-accolade-characters-in-cmake)) with special characters management. So this is not an acceptable solution for me.

I tried to use cached variable, like this:

```
function( QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR var line )
  set( ${var} "${${var}}\n${line}\n" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE )
endfunction()

function( QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR var relline debugline )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "release:${relline} (two functions call)" )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "debug:${debugline} (two functions call)" )
endfunction()

set( FILE_CONTENT "" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE )    
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(FILE_CONTENT "#Generated by CMake scripts!")
QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "foo" "bar" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "release:foo (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "debug:bar (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( FILE_CONTENT "EOF" )

file(WRITE myFile.txt ${FILE_CONTENT} )
```

This works, but then, second time I invoke CMake, I get lots of errors due to invalid `CMakeCache.txt` content.

Any idea to fix that, either with a brand new solution, or with a way to make functions or cached variables work in a better way would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best alternative I found is to actually drop the variable and directly write the file from the function (less efficient, but who really cares...):

```
function( QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR file line )
  file( APPEND ${file} "${line}\n" )
endfunction()

function( QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR file relline debugline )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${file} "release:${relline} (two functions call)" )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${file} "debug:${debugline} (two functions call)" )
endfunction()

file( WRITE myFile.txt "" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR(myFile.txt "#Generated by CMake scripts!")
QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR( myFile.txt "foo" "bar" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( myFile.txt "release:foo (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( myFile.txt "debug:bar (single function call)" )
QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( myFile.txt "EOF" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another `PARENT_SCOPE` assignment in `QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR`, i.e.:

```
function( QMAKE_ADD_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG_LINES_TO_VAR var relline debugline )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "release:${relline} (two functions call)" )
   QMAKE_ADD_LINE_TO_VAR( ${var} "debug:${debugline} (two functions call)" )
   set( ${var} "${${var}}" PARENT_SCOPE )
endfunction()
```